# saying s1 and s2 "value computed is not used", but my final result was right. Why?

Tags: c

I have a basic problem of C language：When I was compiling the code, I encountered a strange warning, saying s1 and s2 "value computed is not used", but my final result was right. Why?

```
static const char *CutStringNchar(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    if ((s1 == NULL) || (s2 == NULL))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    char ch1 = *s1;
    char ch2 = *s2;
    while (1)
    {
        if (ch1 == ch2)
        {
            *s1++;
            *s2++;
            ch1 = *s1;
            ch2 = *s2;
            //printf("ch1 = %c\n", ch1);
            if (ch2 != '\0')
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                return s1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("ret = %s\n", CutStringNchar("test/aa", "test/a"));
    const char *ret = CutStringNchar("test/aa", "test/a");
    printf("%s\n", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

warning:

```
warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
             *s1++;
             ^~~~~
warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
             *s2++;
             ^~~~~
```

result :

```
./a.out
ret = a
a
```

Comment: Those are equivalent to just `s1++; s2++;`.

Comment: What do you think `*s1++` does that is different from `s1++`? Why do you need the `*`?

Comment: The function doesn't seem always to return any value. If the final exit from the function is in an `else` clause it would be clearer using `break` to end the loop.

Comment: @WeatherVane As far as I can see the function will always return from one of the `else` clauses so it should be OK. That said, I strongly agree with your "use `break`" recommendation. IMO, it will make the code much easier to read and understand.

Comment: @4386427 yes it will do that, but the construction (apparently missing any `return` at the end of the function) causes a compiler warning. Those 8 lines could be replaced with `if (ch2 == '\0') break;` followed by the `return s1;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An expression like `*s1++;` includes two operators, i.e. `*` and `++` (post-increment). Unless you are an experienced C programmer, I recommend that you avoid expressions with multiple operators (whenever possible). Instead write the code with multiple expressions.

So instead of:

```
*s1++;
```

do

```
*s1;
s1++;
```

From this it's pretty obvious that `*s1;` isn't doing anything useful. It reads the value of the object pointed to by `s1` but it isn't doing anything with the value! It's not saved, printed or part of some calculation or...

It is just ignored.

That's what your compiler is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

The warning hints at the `*`, not the increment `++`.

Instead of `value computed but...` a message `value fetched but...` would be more clear.

I am not really sure about the algorithm, but the whole thing can be condensed to:

```
while (1)

    if (*s1++ == *s2++) {

        if (*s2 != '\0')
            continue;

        return s1;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
```

No need to have a `ch2` instead of `*s2`. You can, of course, but then the assignments and increments still should fit more nicely into the loop.